# How to remove some columns from a dataset?

Tags: java, text-files, bufferedreader

I am having a large dataset with textfiles (txt-Format). 
The textfiles are containing data in this format:

```
Name, Number, Timestamp, Sensordata1, Sensordata2, ... , Sensordata40
Name, Number, Timestamp, Sensordata1, Sensordata2, ... , Sensordata40
Name, Number, Timestamp, Sensordata1, Sensordata2, ... , Sensordata40
```

**Now I need to remove the Number and the Timestamp from every line.**

My code at the moment:

```
try{
            // Open the file that is the first
            // command line parameter

            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("file.txt");

            // Get the object of DataInputStream
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;

            //Read File Line By Line
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {

                // Print the content on the console
                System.out.println (strLine);
            }

            //Close the input stream
            in.close();
        }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

**How can I do this in Java?**

Comment: Something like `String.split(',')` , get an array and remove what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a few ways this can be accomplished depending on how long you want to spend detecting things like columns etc, the simplest being to statically enter which columns you want to remove in your example number 1 and 2 in respect to an array, this can be done in your example like this :

```
package stackquestions;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

 public class StackQuestions {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       try{
            // Open the file that is the first
            // command line parameter

            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("file.txt");

            // Get the object of DataInputStream
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;

            //Read File Line By Line
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                String[] data=strLine.split(",");


                for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    if(i!=1 && i!=2){
                         System.out.println (data[i]);
                    }

                }
                // Print the content on the console

            }

            //Close the input stream
            in.close();
        }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
}
}
```

Another method is to detect columns based on whether or not the line being read is the first line, split the first line (assuming the first line being read contains headers and subsequently perform a check on the index each iteration to see which column the data belongs to.

Comment: Also note since you are using a comma separated file there are other ways to more formally read that file structured if you are invested in making a more stable program : [link] (http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/). This method would also allow more flexibility in changing which columns to remove at a later data without referencing statically entered numbers such as 1 & 2. Either way hope it helped, and good luck :)

Comment: Great reference! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

If the same values will always appear in the same column, then I'm sure you could just add all the values to an `ArrayList`, loop the removal of the values you don't need, and then just write it back to the file.